# EJB 3 Transactions Service Facade

Tags: transactions, ejb, rollback

I'm trying to implement the Service Facade Pattern,

I have some jars that are deploying in differents OAS´s containers, inside the jars there are Stateless  EJBs 3.0 that have some methods that are consume via RMI, those methods are called via RMI from Wars apps

But now we have a new requirement, from one War I have to call 3 methods from differents jars files that are in differents containers inside one transaction, and if some method in some jar fail I have to do a rollback in all the methods.

Example:

JAR A, have the EJB "A" that is deploy in the OAS Container "OAS A" and have the method "A()"

JAR B, have the EJB "B" that is deploy in the OAS Container "OAS B" and have the method "B()"

JAR C, have the EJB "C" that is deploy in the OAS Container "OAS C" and have the method "C()"

WAR Z, is deploy in OAS Container "OAS Z" have to call the method A() B() y C() in a transacction.

Since in the War file we cannot manage transactions, we create a new app that is in a jar file called ServiceFacade.jar and is deployed in the OAS Container "OAS SF" and have an EJB "SF" that calls the A() B() C() of the other Ejbs via RMI.

So the WAR Z calls via RMI the serviceFacade method that calls the 3 methods, all works fine.

The Problem?

Inside the EJB SF we use the UserTransaction object to manage the transaction in this way:

```
   @Stateless(name="SF")
   @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
   @ApplicationException(rollback = true)
   public class ServiceFacade ...
   @Resource private UserTransaction userTx;
    public void test() {
        try {
            userTx.begin();
            getEJBA().A();
            getEJBB().B();
            getEJBC().C();
            userTx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            try {
                if (userTx != null && 
                    (userTx.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_ACTIVE || 
                     userTx.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK)) {
                    System.out.println("Rollback!!");
                    userTx.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SystemException ex) {
                throw new SIGNOSException(SIGNOSException.DEFAULT_EXCEPTION, 
                                          ex.getMessage());
            }
            throw (SIGNOSException)e;
        }
    }
```

But when from the war Z the test() method is called and some method inside the transaction, lets say getEJBB().B(); fails, the method getEJBA().A(); doesn´t rollback!!

What we can do? We also tried with the TransactionManagementType.Container and @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) but neither did the rollback, even do the message "Rollback!!" is print in console.

Hope you experts can help me.

Thanks!!!